# AWS SNS sound for iOS push notification not happening

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I have an SNS triggered by a lambda on AWS that generates an iOS push notification, is working fine, but the problem is that the sound is not happening...

```
const sns = new AWS.SNS();


var payload = {
  default: ' World23',

  APNS: {
    aps: {
      alert: 'tkt',
      sound: 'default',
      badge: 1
    }
  }
};
// first have to stringify the inner APNS object...
payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);
// then have to stringify the entire message payload
payload = JSON.stringify(payload);


  var params = {
      Message:payload,
      MessageStructure: 'json',

      Subject: event.body.subject,
      TargetArn:TargetArn
      };
      sns.publish(params, function(err,data){
          if(err) {
              console.error('error publishing to SNS',err);
              context.fail(err);
          } else {
              console.info('message published to SNS',data);
              done(null, data);
          }
      });
```

What is wrong with my payload?, the sound and badge are not getting set.
Cheers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatting for the body needed some tweaks, also the environment was the "sandbox", will have to change for prod push notifications "APNS"...

```
const sns = new AWS.SNS();
  var payload = {
      default: notifMessage,

      'APNS_SANDBOX': {
        'aps': {
          'alert': notifMessage,
          'sound': 'default',
          'badge': 1
        }
      }, 


// first have to stringify the inner APNS object...
  payload.APNS_SANDBOX = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS_SANDBOX);
// then have to stringify the entire message payload
  payload = JSON.stringify(payload);


  var params = {
      // Message: event.body.message, 
      Message:payload,
      MessageStructure: 'json',

      Subject: event.body.subject,
      TargetArn:TargetArn
      };
      console.log('params:: ', payload);
      sns.publish(params, function(err,data){
          if(err) {
              console.error('error publishing to SNS',err);
              context.fail(err);
          } else {
              console.info('message published to SNS',data);
              done(null, data);
          }
      });
```